# OPC UA Secure Connection C#

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I am trying to establish a secure connection using OPCUA Client wiht a Beckhoff Server. I get an error Control Certificate is not trusted. Any suggestions on how to proceed from here?

```
public bool connect(string url) {
        // TODO implement security
        // select the best endpoint.
        EndpointDescription endpointDescription;

        try {
            endpointDescription  = ClientUtils.SelectEndpoint(url, true);
        } catch {
            return false;
        }



        endpointDescription.SecurityPolicyUri = SecurityPolicies.Basic128Rsa15;
        endpointDescription.SecurityMode = MessageSecurityMode.SignAndEncrypt;


        EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = EndpointConfiguration.Create(appConfig());

        ConfiguredEndpoint endpoint = new ConfiguredEndpoint(null, endpointDescription, endpointConfiguration);


            m_session = Session.Create(
            appConfig(),
            endpoint,
            false,
            false,
            "Experiment",
            60000,
            useridentety,
            preferredLocales);

        // set up keep alive callback.
        // TODO Verbindungsabbrüche behandeln
        //m_session.KeepAlive += new KeepAliveEventHandler(Session_KeepAlive);

        return m_session.Connected;
    }
```

Error:

```
2016-07-06 14:34:58.6683|ERROR|Control|Certificate is not trusted.
SubjectName: CN=TcOpcUaServer@192.168.3.222, OU=Unit, O=Organization, L=LocationName, C=DE, DC=CX-25C711 IssuerName: CN=TcOpcUaServer@192.168.3.222, OU=Unit, O=Organization, L=LocationName, C=DE, DC=CX-25C711 bei Opc.Ua.CertificateValidator.Validate(X509Certificate2Collection chain) in C:\VIPA_OPC_NetClient\UANET\Stack\Core\Security\Certificates\CertificateValidator.cs:Zeile 249.bei Opc.Ua.CertificateValidator.Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate) in C:\VIPA_OPC_NetClient\UA-NET\Stack\Core\Security\Certificates\CertificateValidator.cs:Zeile 161.
   bei Opc.Ua.Client.Session.Open(String sessionName, UInt32 sessionTimeout, IUserIdentity identity, IList`1 preferredLocales) in C:\OPC_NetClient\UA-NET\SampleApplications\SampleLibraries\Client\Session.cs:Zeile 1980.
   bei Opc.Ua.Client.Session.Create(ApplicationConfiguration configuration, ConfiguredEndpoint endpoint, Boolean updateBeforeConnect, Boolean checkDomain, String sessionName, UInt32 sessionTimeout, IUserIdentity identity, IList`1 preferredLocales) in C:\OPC_NetClient\UA-NET\SampleApplications\SampleLibraries\Client\Session.cs:Zeile 818.
   bei PerformanceTest.Experiment.connect(String url) in C:\OPC_NetClient\PerformanceTest\Experiment.cs:Zeile 210.
   bei PerformanceTest.MainForm.runExperiment() in C:\OPC_NetClient\PerformanceTest\MainForm.cs:Zeile 148.
2016-07-06 14:34:58.6683|ERROR|Control|Certificate is not trusted.
SubjectName: CN=TcOpcUaServer@192.168.3.222, OU=Unit, O=Organization, L=LocationName, C=DE, DC=CX-25C711
IssuerName: CN=TcOpcUaServer@192.168.3.222, OU=Unit, O=Organization, L=LocationName, C=DE, DC=CX-25C711
   bei Opc.Ua.CertificateValidator.InternalValidate(X509Certificate2Collection certificates) in C:\VIPA_OPC_NetClient\UA-NET\Stack\Core\Security\Certificates\CertificateValidator.cs:Zeile 755.
   bei Opc.Ua.CertificateValidator.Validate(X509Certificate2Collection chain) in C:\VIPA_OPC_NetClient\UA-NET\Stack\Core\Security\Certificates\CertificateValidator.cs:Zeile 189.
2016-07-06 14:34:58.6933|ERROR|Control|Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei PerformanceTest.Experiment.disconnect() in C:\OPC_NetClient\PerformanceTest\Experiment.cs:Zeile 254.
   bei PerformanceTest.MainForm.runExperiment() in C:\OPC_NetClient\PerformanceTest\MainForm.cs:Zeile 168.
2016-07-06 14:34:58.6933|INFO|Control|Done running experiment
```

Comment: which opc ua library are you using?

Comment: You should add more info about the error you're getting

Comment: @JSantos I have added the Error to the post. Sorry, its quite messy.

Answer (score 1):

The validation of your certificate is failling, because the CN on your certificate is not trusted by the server.I suppose you generated the certificate yourself, maybe TcOpcUaServer@192.168.3.222 is not considered valid by the server.I don´t know how the Beckhoff server works, you should ask the developer for help on this subject.

Also the IssuerName and SubjectName shouldn´t be equal.

A good tool to check the data in a certificate is [keystore-explorer](http://www.keystore-explorer.org/)

Bit latte sorry, but hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks man. I found the problem. It was indeed the calidation of the certificate. Had to manually change the trusted certificates on the server.